# Can't include a class file in functions file PHP

Tags: php

I have this dbconnect.php file that uses a class called DB to do DB operations. I have another file that contains some general functions called functions.php. This dbconnect file is working well in everywhere but functions.php. What could be the problem?

Comment: I've no idea...., path declarations maybe?

Comment: Most likely a Layer 8 problem, since you haven't shown any relevant code that'd actually let us help you.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: when I include another file in the same path, there aren't any problems.

Comment: When I put that code error_reporting... it doesn't completely crash the execution but the functions doesn't work well. Marc B, what is a Layer 8 problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using include_once instead of includes.

Also, it would help if you could c+p the error you are receiving.

Comment: The error is "Internal Server Error". This happens only when I try to include dbconnect.php file. It has a class code inside that has constructor, destructor, some functions and object creation.

Comment: I just tried include_once and it worked :) Thanks man, any idea why?

Comment: You included a file that is already included in the file you included.
Glad it works, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Using include_once instead of include, solved my problem. I think it was caused because of object orientation. My best guess is, when I used include, the class was c/p'd multiple times which interfered the core of object orientation concept.